# QGIS geometry definition x field y field drop down menu not working?

Tags: qgis, geometry, latitude-longitude

I am trying to create contours with QGIS. This is my first time and I'm following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4Rp318vM1Y&ab_channel=Geocarto

I got to 3:05 where I am to put the x field as longitude, the y as latitude and, the z field as altitude. However, the drop down menus are only allowing one option "type longitude latitude altitude..." but not the any of the actual options. I have tried typing it on my keyboard but nothing happens.

[image: trying to change x field to longitude]

[image: what comes up]

Comment: Try checking your field delimiter. Looks like it is not comma but tab or whitespace.